# Make WPF create files inside bin folder

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows

I got a C# WPF application which will be inside of the Program Files folder. It will create a simple text file inside the bin folder, but I get a restricted access error (I'm not running the program as admin).
Is there a way to make the bin folder have Write access by default when it gets compiled?

Compiled the WPF and moved the bin generated folder into Program Files

Comment: it is restricted for security reason , so that malware can not overwrite the files, use the user file space for that purpose `Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData`

Comment: You should create such artifacts in the user's temp folder. You can use the static `Path.GetTempPath()` method to obtain the path. Or if the files are meant to be persistent use the folder of your application inside the AppData folder (as already suggested).